# how make a calculation with elastic document fields?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I need to make some calculation  with each doc's some fields and then return it as response's part
I've written this

```
 TermsAggregationBuilder subAggregation = AggregationBuilders
            .terms("price")
            .script(new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless",

                    "            int total = 0;\n" +
                            "            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {\n" +
                            "              total += doc['age'].value;\n" +
                            "            }\n" +
                            "            return total ;\n"
                    , Collections.emptyMap()));
    NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
            .addAggregation(subAggregation)
            .build();
SearchHits<Stories>
            searchHits = elasticsearchOperations.search(nativeSearchQuery, Stories.class
            , IndexCoordinates.of("long_stories"));
```

and this returns this one

```
{
"totalHits": 1,
"totalHitsRelation": "EQUAL_TO",
"maxScore": 1,
"scrollId": null,
"searchHits": [
    {
        "id": "44",
        "score": 1,
        "sortValues": [],
        "content": {
            "id": "44",
            "innerId": 5,
            "age": 44,
            "salary": 433,
            "mark": 10,
            "state": "state",
            "stores": [
                {
                    "storiesId": "44",
                    "innerId": 1
                },
                {
                    "storiesId": "44b",
                    "innerId": 2
                },
                {
                    "storiesId": "44c",
                    "innerId": 3
                }
            ],
            "esh": null
        },
        "highlightFields": {}
    }
],
"aggregations": {
    "asMap": {
        "price": {
            "name": "price",
            "metadata": null,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "aggregations": {
                        "asMap": {},
                        "fragment": true
                    },
                    "keyAsString": "220",
                    "docCount": 1,
                    "docCountError": 0,
                    "key": "220",
                    "keyAsNumber": 220,
                    "fragment": true
                }
            ],
            "type": "sterms",
            "docCountError": 0,
            "sumOfOtherDocCounts": 0,
            "fragment": true
        }
    },
    "fragment": true
},
"empty": false
```

}

this response gives separate calculation I need it to be with above part ,and also if key which is 220 now if I had some another doc which would give the same answer then response would print 220 and doc count 2 I need it to be separately and in above response
like doc1 220 doc2 220 and in above response where actual data holds

Comment: terms aggregation  works as "group by". So it will have only unique keys and documents clubbed under those keys. If you need it on per document basis use scripted field in query instead of aggregationb

Comment: Hi thanks I did that like this ScriptField and added to query withScriptedField but now it returns scripted field like age and others null

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9279354/jaspreet-chahal.   it is now separate but other fields get null

Comment: You will need to specifically provide  "_source": ["*"],

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9279354/jaspreet-chahal.  I just have no idea where to put it

Comment: in my script where to put it ? please could you tell me

Comment: It is not part of script . It is part of  search request. I am not aware of java framework. It should be something like nativeSearchQuery.addSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilter(includeSources)) or  nativeSearchQuery.fetchSource(true). includeSources is list of string field-names

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9279354/jaspreet-chahal.  Thank you very much it solved all my problems thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Terms aggregation works as "group by".
So it will have only unique keys and documents clubbed under those keys. If you need it on per document basis use scripted field in query instead of aggregation.

With scripted field you will need to specify "source" to fetch rest of the document.

You can also explore [runtime field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime.html) in place of scripted field. It offer some benefits over scripted field

> You can use script fields to access values in _source and return
> calculated values based on a script valuation. Runtime fields have
> these same capabilities, but provide greater flexibility because you
> can query and aggregate on runtime fields in a search request. Script
> fields can only fetch values.